# I am getting an error while trying to calculate if a number is palaindrome?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    System.out.println("Enter here:  ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    number = sc.nextInt();
    int reverse=0;

    while(number!=0) {
        int rel = number%10;
        reverse = (reverse*10)+ rel;
        number = number/10;
    }

    if (number == reverse ) {
        System.out.println("the number is palaindrome " + reverse);
    } else {
        System.out.println("the number is not palaindrome " + reverse);
    }
}
```

Every time I am getting *the number is not palindrome* output even if the input is palindrome.

Comment: check out the value of `number` after leaving the `while` loop, additionally to checking your `while` condition ;) i´m certain you´ll notice it :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are updating the `number`.

Store it locally and then operate it in `while` loop.

```
    int lNum = number;
    while(number!=0) {
                int rel = number%10;
                reverse = (reverse*10)+ rel;
                number= number/10;
    }

    if (lNum == reverse ) {
                System.out.println("the number is palaindrome "+reverse );
    }else
                System.out.println("the number is not palaindrome "+reverse);
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/Ar6cmH) working after correction.

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the origial number (number) in the while loop as well. 
So in the if statement number will never be equal to the reverse.

Save your number in a temporary variable to use it in a while loop.
Your final code should look like this.

```
int temp = number;


    while(temp!=0) {
        int rel = temp%10;
        reverse = (reverse*10)+ rel;
        temp= temp/10;
    }

    if (number == reverse ) {
        System.out.println("the number is palaindrome "+reverse );
    }else
        System.out.println("the number is not palaindrome "+reverse);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep current value (**temp**) and then compare actual value which you saved (temp) with reverse one, below I am sharing code which I tried locally.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        System.out.println("Enter here:  ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = sc.nextInt();
        int reverse = 0;

        int temp = number;

        while (number != 0) {
            int rel = number % 10;
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + rel;
            number = number / 10;
        }

        String resMessage = temp == reverse ? "the number is palaindrome " + reverse
            : "the number is not palaindrome " + reverse;

    System.out.println(resMessage);
    }
}
```

And just a suggestion, if you are asking question on SO then try to put brief description of what you are looking for. This will help other folks here to provide you best solution.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you reassign number here `number = number/10;`.
you can save a reference to `number` and work with that here `if (numberRef == reverse ) {`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int number;
System.out.println("Enter here:  ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
number = sc.nextInt();
int numberRef = number;
int reverse=0;

while(number != 0) {
    int rel = number%10 == 0 ? 0 : number % 10;
    reverse = (reverse*10) + rel;
    number= number/10;
}

if (numberRef == reverse ) {
    System.out.println("the number is palaindrome "+reverse );
}  else
    System.out.println("the number is not palaindrome " + reverse);

    /*Everytime I am getting the number is not palaindrome output even if the input is palaindrome.*/

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the number variable is 0 after while loop.  And you also check it like.      0 ==  reverse .

Its the problem in your code. Is it possible to input as a String? Then have a small solution.